# Formula to create a radial gradient

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm writing a piece of software that generates a radial gradient and need some help working out the correct formula. So far, with the current algorithm, it's creating a grayish center, fades to solid white, then finally to black. It should, however, fade straight from white to black.

[image]

Here is how I'm going about creating the gradient...

First, I get the center of the image:

> $centerX = width \cdot 0.5$
>
> $centerY = height \cdot 0.5$

Calculate the distance from the center to x, y (x & y can be any value between 0 and width or height):

> $distanceFromCenter = \sqrt{((centerX-x)^2)+((centerY-y)^2)}$

Once we know the distance we can solve for a

> $a = \frac{distanceFromCenter-centerY}{distanceFromCenter - height}$

Lastly, we then linear interpolate the result so we can use it as color value between 0 and 255

> $pixel = (0 - 255) \cdot(a+0)$

If you are interested, here is the actual code in C#:

```
    public float[,] radGrad(int width, int height, float threshold) {
       float[,] grad = new float[width, height];
       float cX = width * 0.5f;
       float cY = height * 0.5f;

       for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
          for(int x =0; x < width; ++x) {
             float distFromCenter = distance(cX, cY, x, y);
             float pixel = (Math.Max(distFromCenter, cY) - Math.Min(distFromCenter, cY)) / (Math.Max(distFromCenter, height) - Math.Min(distFromCenter, height));
             pixel = fLerp(pixel, 255, 0);
             grad[x, y] = pixel;
           }
        }

        return grad;
   }

    private float fLerp(float norm, float min, float max) {
       return (max - min) * norm + min;
    }

    private float distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
       return (float)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Abs(x1 - x2), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Abs(y1 - y2), 2) ));
    }
```

So, in summery, I need to create a radial gradient that fades from solid white to solid black. What is the correct formula to do so?

---

Edit: here is a picture of the desired result
[image]

Comment: Do you want solid black in the center of each edge or at the corners?

Comment: I added a picture of what the gradient should look like, more or less.

Comment: float maxDist = distance(cX,cY,width,height);
     //...
        float distFromCenterNormalized = Math.min(distance(cX, cY, x, y) / maxDist,1);
        grad[x, y] = fLerp(distFromCenterNormalized, 255, 0);

Comment: Please create an answer!